# Setting Up an Async Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Would someone point me in the right Direction Setting Up an Async Task? I have a InitializeDatabases Method with the following Task:

```
    Task.Run(async () => 
        {
            await NContext.ZSA_TransactionHeader.LoadAsync();
            await NContext.ZSA_TransactionDetail.LoadAsync();
            await DContext.AR_MasterTable.LoadAsync();
            await DContext.IN_Master.LoadAsync();
            await DContext.SA_HistoryHeader.LoadAsync();
            await DContext.SA_HistoryDetail.LoadAsync();
            await DContext.SA_NonInvCode.LoadAsync();
            await DContext.SA_SalespCode.LoadAsync();
        }).Wait();
```

My problem is that the task executes but continues even when it has not finished loading. I need it to wait until all the .LoadAsync tasks are complete. I would also like all the LoadAsync tasks to run concurrently. I have gathered this much from other SO questions but I feel like I am in over my head with this.

Comment: @SLaks: Whoops, you're absolutely right - sorry! Will delete my comment, then tidy up after you've deleted yours...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By `await`ing each call, you're waiting for each one to finish before starting the next one.

By calling `.Wait()` at the end, you're freezing your UI anyway.

You want `await Task.WhenAll(x.LoadAsync(), y.LoadAsync(), ...)`.